# Zimbra 8.0.6 mails waiting on deferred queue

Tags: zimbra

We are using a zimbra community edition server on cloud, version 8.0.6.GA.5922.UBUNTU12.64 UBUNTU12_64 FOSS edition.

It was working fine until yesterday. This morning incoming mails suddenly stop delivering to mailboxes, outgoing mails are working just fine.

I've looked into the administration console, it seems all inbound e-mails are being held on the deferred queue with no exception. I've made no modifications to the system whatsoever.

I've also looked at the logs but really don't know where to start looking, or even what to look for.

Could you guys help me about this?

Comment: try to look in `/var/log/zimbra.log` or `/var/log/maillog`

Comment: Thanks masegaloeh, that's been very helpful. I found that zimbra is unable to resolve its own address, after that I've solved it as I've stated in answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems problem has caused from the dns server of the vps provider. It somehow was not resolving our domain name, in spite of url of the virtual server staticly stated on hosts file.

I think that is because zimbra does not rely on the hosts file and tries to resolve the address each time it needs to. This caused server's own url not to be resolved and thus mails not delivered to their recipients.

What we did was using google's dns servers by entering the following line to the /etc/network/interfaces file, both for the loopback and eth0 adapters.

```
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

After that zimbra started to solve its own address and mails got delivered. Hope this helps to someone out there.